# Why $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{F(n,n)}{F(n-1,n)} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{F(n+1,n)}{F(n,n)} $?

Tags: limits-and-convergence, recurrences

Let $\alpha,\beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}^+$ be  and the function

$$ F(m,n)= \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $m n=0$ }; \\
 \alpha F(m ,n-1)+ \beta F(m-1,n )+ \gamma F(m-1,n-1), & \text{ if $m n>0$. }%
\end{cases}
$$
Please, a proof for $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{F(n,n)}{F(n-1,n)} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{F(n+1,n)}{F(n,n)} $$

Comment: Probably won't help.  Generating function $$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{\it F} \left( n,m \right) {x}^{n}{y}^{m} =-{\frac {\alpha\,xy+\beta\,xy-\alpha\,x-\beta\,y-xy+1}{ \left( y-1 \right)  \left( x-1 \right)  \left( \gamma\,xy+\alpha\,x+\beta\,y-1 \right) }}$$

Comment: Actually that's how one would start.  Then use the contour-integral formula
to get algebraic generating functions for the diagonal series with
$m=n$ and $m = n \pm 1$, and use the singularities nearest the origin 
to recover asymptotic formulas for those series.